# How to change normal core data into back ground?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I have core data in my app, which is running in main thread. But for now I'm receiving some large amount of data from server and saving to coredata, and now my is getting slow. I've searched for solution in stack over flow and found that i need to use back ground core data saving. So will it solve my problem?

If it is , I'm confused how to change present methods into background core data?

This is the code I'm using right now for saving into Core data.

```
     -(void)insertToUserEntityWithData:(NSMutableDictionary *)inDictionary

 {

   AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication   sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];

UserInfo *userInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserInfo"
                      inManagedObjectContext:context];

if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"userEmail"])
{
    if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"]!=[NSNull null])
    {
        userInfo.userEmail=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"];
    }
}
if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"password"])
{
    if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"password"]!=[NSNull null])
    {
        userInfo.password=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"password"];
    }
}
if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isCurrentUser"])
{
    if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isCurrentUser"]!=[NSNull null])
    {
        userInfo.isCurrentUser=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isCurrentUser"] boolValue]];
    }
}
if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"login_time"])
{
    if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"login_time"]!=[NSNull null])
    {
        userInfo.loginTimestamp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[inDictionary valueForKey:@"login_time"]];

    }
}

if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"sid"]!=[NSNull null])
{
    userInfo.sessionID=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"sid"];
}

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not insert to userInfo: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

}
```

**UPDATED CODE CRASHED**

```
 015-04-08 12:59:32.935 Inxed[3401:158275] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Parent NSManagedObjectContext must use either NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType or NSMainQueueConcurrencyType.'
*** First throw call stack:
 (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x035fb946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03284a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreData                            0x013b224d -[NSManagedObjectContext setParentContext:] + 269
3   Inxed                               0x002463de __55-[IXDataBaseManager updateThreadEntityWithSyncDetails:]_block_invoke + 318
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03fa030a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03fc0e2f _dispatch_client_callout + 14
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03fa6afc _dispatch_queue_drain + 1475
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03fa63c3 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 212
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03fa9067 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 466
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03faa84a _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 115
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0431c296 _pthread_wqthread + 724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04319eea start_wqthread + 30
 )
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**managedObjectContext**

```
  - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
  managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];


if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

**retrieveCurrentUserDetailsForUser**

```
  -(UserInfo *)retrieveCurrentUserDetailsForUser:(NSString*)inUserEmail
{
  AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserInfo"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *userPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userEmail == %@",inUserEmail];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:userPredicate];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
if(fetchedObjects.count!=0)
{
    UserInfo *userInfo=[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    return userInfo;
}

return nil;

}
```

**CRASH LOG**

```
   2015-04-08 14:17:29.789 Inxed[3519:170514] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'UserInfo''

 *** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x03673946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x032fca97 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreData                            0x013d8ba9 +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 281
3   Inxed                               0x002cf47c -[IXDataBaseManager retrieveCurrentUserDetailsForUser:] + 316
4   Inxed                               0x001a9268 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 2552
5   UIKit                               0x01ccd97c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 291
6   UIKit                               0x01cce687 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2869
7   UIKit                               0x01cd1c0d -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1639
8   UIKit                               0x01cea7d0 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
9   UIKit                               0x01cd081f -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
10  FrontBoardServices                  0x056ed9de __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
11  FrontBoardServices                  0x056ed46f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
12  FrontBoardServices                  0x056ff425 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 26
13  CoreFoundation                      0x035971c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0358cad3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0358c92b __CFRunLoopRun + 2715
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0358bbcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0358b9fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
18  UIKit                               0x01cd01e4 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
19  UIKit                               0x01cd38b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
20  Inxed                               0x002160ad main + 141
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x04064ac9 start + 1
22  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: write this code inside background block.

Comment: but Server will send data frequently, so will there be any issue of thread killing or Partial exection?

Comment: chek it out, but i don't think it'll create any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your background Queue, dispatch your insertion code on that queue by creating a contextFor that block

**Dont use mainContext on background threads**

See the modified code.

```
-(void)insertToUserEntityWithData:(NSMutableDictionary *)inDictionary

{
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("backgroundQueueName", NULL);

    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication   sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];

        NSManagedObjectContext *contextforThread = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

        contextforThread.parentContext = context;

        UserInfo *userInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserInfo"
                              inManagedObjectContext:contextforThread];

        if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"userEmail"])
        {
            if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"]!=[NSNull null])
            {
                userInfo.userEmail=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"];
            }
        }
        if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"password"])
        {
            if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"password"]!=[NSNull null])
            {
                userInfo.password=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"password"];
            }
        }
        if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isCurrentUser"])
        {
            if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isCurrentUser"]!=[NSNull null])
            {
                userInfo.isCurrentUser=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isCurrentUser"] boolValue]];
            }
        }
        if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"login_time"])
        {
            if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"login_time"]!=[NSNull null])
            {
                userInfo.loginTimestamp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[inDictionary valueForKey:@"login_time"]];

            }
        }

        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"sid"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            userInfo.sessionID=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"sid"];
        }

        if (![contextforThread save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Could not insert to userInfo: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSError *error;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Could not insert to userInfo: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
            else
            {
                //Post a notification or call method for tableview reload here
            }

        });


    });


}
```

**EDIT**

In your AppDelegate.m find your method **managedObjectContext**

and make the following change

```
managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

**EDIT 2**

See my Core Data Methods. make changes accordingly.

**Please see :** your NSManagedObjectContext should be created only in your - (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext method

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }

    //[managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];
    return managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

    return managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        NSLog(@"old persistent returned!!!");
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                                               stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"<Project Name>.sqlite"]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                                  initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if(![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                 configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/
    }
    NSLog(@"new persistent created!!!");
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74731/discussion-on-answer-by-mayur-deshmukh-how-to-change-normal-core-data-into-back).

Answer (score 0):

Create a private context from your backgground thread and set it's parent context as main context.

```
NSManagedObjectContext* childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
childContext.parentContext = self.mainContext;
```

insert/update/delete your managed objects using this childcontext in the background thread then save the child along with the main context as follows

```
[childContext performBlock:^{
   // do something that takes some time asynchronously using the temp context

  // push to parent
  NSError *error;
  if (![childContext save:&amp;error])
  {
    // handle error
  }

  // save parent to disk asynchronously
 [self.mainContext performBlock:^{
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.mainContext save:&amp;error])
    {
      // handle error
   }
 }];
}];
```

Comment: I have tried, but getting crash. can you make litle bit more detailed the code?